# Alexa setup not recognizing router password

Tags: router, echo

After I choose my WiFi router in the Alexa app, I'm asked to enter my router password. For some odd reason, Alexa won't take it. Tried resetting my Arris router/cable modem AND Alexa and got nada. Any idea out there?

Comment: I don't have experience with Alexa, but I'm wondering why it wants your *router* password. Are you sure it doesn't want the wifi password, so it can access the network?

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question. Please read [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 0):

As @djsmiley2k suggested, the Alexa app is probably looking for your **WiFi password**, rather than your router password, so it can connect to your local network. Unless you are configuring a service or skill to log into your router and perform some task, the Alexa app won't need the password to the router itself.

However, if it *does* need the router's actual password (for a specific skill or service) and it's not working, I have seen an Arris router have password issues like that in the past. The fix is to select the option to change the router's password (through the web interface) and use the same password -- just retype it. For whatever reason, the router won't recognize the correct password, but refreshing the password should fix that issue.